# Laravel Factories - Create or Make dynamic

Tags: database, laravel, testing, factory, relation

I have simple question.

How could I write a Factory that let me defines relationships that use `make()` or `create()` depending on original call `make()` or `create()`?

It is my use case:

I have a simple factory

```php
/** @var $factory Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'role_id' => factory(Role::class),
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => 'secret',
    ];
});
```

My problem is with that **role_id**. When using `factory(Role::class)`, it will create a Role always! Writing in Database...

In my tests, when I write `factory(User::class)->create();` It will create an User and Role, thats ok!

But if I write `factory(User::class)->make();` It will still create a Role... I wont write in Database a Role when using `make()`, in that case, I just want a simple `role_id => 0`.

How could I achieve that?

Thanks!

**Edit (Workaround)**

Well, it was harder than expected, there is no way to know when using `make()` or `create()` when your are defining nested relationships... The only way I found is using `debug_stacktrace()` method, and look for that make method called from Factory.

For simplification and reusability, I created a helper method for Factories called `associateTo($class)`, this method will define relationships in Factory. It will return an existing ID from related model when using `create()` or 1 when using `make()`.

By this way, Factories can be:

```php
/** @var $factory Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'role_id' => associateTo(Role::class), // Defining relationship
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => 'secret',
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

The helper function is:

```php
/**
 * Helper that returns an ID of a specified Model (by class name).
 * If there are any Model, it will grab one randomly, if not, it will create a new one using it's Factory
 * When using make() it wont write in Database, instead, it will return a 1
 *
 * @param string $modelClass
 * @param array $attributes
 * @param bool $forceNew
 * @return int
 */
function associateTo(string $modelClass, array $attributes = [])
{
    $isMaking = collect(debug_backtrace())
        // A function called 'make()'
        ->filter(fn ($item) => isset($item['function']) && $item['function'] === 'make') 
        // file where I have global functions
        ->filter(fn ($item) => isset($item['file']) && Str::endsWith($item['file'], 'functions.php')) 
        ->count();

    if ($isMaking) return 1;

    /** @var Model $model */
    $model = resolve($modelClass);

    return optional($model::inRandomOrder()->first())->id
        ?? create($modelClass, $attributes)->id; // call to Factory
}
```

With this, I can write Unit test easily (using Factories) without the need of using Database connections, so **Unit Tests becomes superfast!**

I hope this help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite attribute **role_id**:

```
factory(User::class)->make(['role_id' => 0]);
```

Another solution - helper method for any attribute with `_id` ending:

```
function make($class)
{
    $attributes = \Schema::getColumnListing((new $class)->getTable());
    $exclude_attribures = [];

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
    {
        if(ends_with($attribute, '_id'))
        {
            $exclude_attribures[] = [$attribute => 0];
        }
    }

    return factory($class)->make($exclude_attribures);
}
```

Call example:

```
make(User:class);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know, but I would like that get done automatically when calling `make()`, because it will be overhelming if I have to overwrite all relationships attributes of every model each time I just want use `factory(...)->make()`... Maybe I can create a testing global function called `make(MyClass::class)`, that overwrites all '_id ending' attributes with 0, but I still dont know how could I achieve that, specially with nested factories relationships.

Comment: I have added helper method

Comment: Thank you, that was close, but I could not use it beacause I'm avoiding using Database, so method `getColumnListing()` is not working, however, I can use `rawOf(class)` from Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory :) but, it still failing when defining nested relationships :(

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of states

```php
/** @var $factory Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'role_id' => factory(Role::class),
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => 'secret',
    ];
});

$factory->state(App\User::class, 'withoutRelationship', [
    'role_id' => null,
    'another_id' => null,
]);
```

Then

```php
factory(User::class)->state('withoutRelationship')->make();
```